# ACPI error AE_NOT_FOUND with same motherboard replaced

Tags: 16.04, boot, bios

My Shuttle barebone has broken down after two months. I sent it back to customer service who changed the motherboard and they also updated the BIOS (so BIOS version is not the same as on previous system).

Now when I connect my HDD, I see errors and system failed to boot :

```
[ 1.474485] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure. AE_NOT_FOUND (20170531/psargs-364)
[ 1.474577] ACPI Error:  Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT2._GTF. AE_NO_FOUND (20170531/psparse-550)
[ 1.482152] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure. AE_NOT_FOUND (20170531/psargs-364)
[ 1.482296] ACPI Error:  Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT2._GTF. AE_NO_FOUND (20170531/psparse-550)
/dev/sda5: recovering journal
/dev/sda5: clean, 419821/7331840 files , 2934231/29296640 blocks
Welcome to emergency mode! After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or ^D to try again to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance
(or press Control-D to continue):
```

I run Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit with linux kernel 4.13.0.37 and legacy BIOS.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The kernel drivers/ata/libata-acpi.c driver calls this ACPI method.  The SATA (Serial ATA bus interface that connects to block devices) ACPI (Advanced Configuration and Power Interface)  driver calls the _GTF control method in your firmware (BIOS) to re-initialize the drive.  The _GTF method returns a bunch of ATA commands that are sent to the drive to restore the drive to the boot up defaults.

The error you are seeing is because your firmware does not have a _GTF method defined. This may be intentional as your hardware may not need these ATA commands, or it may be a bug because the BIOS vendor forgot to put them in. However, if your SATA drives are working correctly without error then it most probably is just not required and you need not worry about this kernel driver message.

Comment: Many thanks for your detailled answer, I understand better how it works. I cannot boot system. Is there a fix that I can try to boot ?

Comment: Does your machine always break in the same way each time you reboot it?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what happens

Comment: I suspect the ' journalctl -xb' command may provide some more clues to why it is failing like this, but I'm not an expert in systemd, so perhaps somebody else can help you on that

Comment: Have you fixed the problem? I have the same problem, but it just suddenly happened to start. @CélineGarel