# ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND when booting after upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: 20.04, grub2, kernel, 22.04, acpi

I upgraded my Ubuntu version from 20.04 to 22.04 (dual boot), and now I get ACPI errors when I boot, but when I load an older kernel version (5.13.0-48-generic), so I only get this errors with the 5.15.0.37-generic.

I saw some solutions where someone suggest to turn ACPI off, but I don't think that's a good solution.

Error messages when booting:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find acpi drivers for specific acpi device / Solving kernel suspend bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198969/how-to-find-acpi-drivers-for-specific-acpi-device-solving-kernel-suspend-bug)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error AE\_NOT\_FOUND with same motherboard replaced](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030310/acpi-error-ae-not-found-with-same-motherboard-replaced) It looks like this is a warning and not an error, it may be ignored.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)

Answer (score 5):

These messages indicate that there are BIOS errors related to power management control and PCI root bridge enumeration data due to an improper ACPI table. While these should not cause problems with regular system operation, they could cause issues with power management functions. Please contact your system vendor and ask for an updated BIOS.
See [this page](https://access.redhat.com/articles/65378) for more info.

Comment: @RishonJR *or*, the BIOS in question hasn't implemented certain BIOS functions that Linux tests for.  This is common in HP laptops as an example.

Comment: Oh Sorry. I'm relatively to linux-firmware related issues, and i just prescribes whatever similarly has happened to my HP laptop.

Comment: No need to apologise. That is a reasonable question

Comment: “Please contact your system vendor and ask for an updated BIOS” Gigabyte won't release an update for my 10 years old motherboard, the last BIOS was released in 2013. What other options do we have?

Comment: I rode too quickly sorry, “these should not cause problems with regular system operation”, it works for me, my system is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since my bios is up-to-date, I have selected kernel version 5.13.0-48 as default and always boot with this. Works without problems and wait for future updates.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved after upgrading the Nouveau drivers to Nvidia-drivers. These errors where showing up on boot and on shutdown, and system was hanging on shutdown. For how to choose the Nvidia drivers for your system see https://askubuntu.com/a/1483375/755271