# Ubuntu 22.04 stuck at shutdown

Tags: shutdown

I am having this weird problem in **Ubuntu 22.04**. My laptop gets stuck at the shutdown screen every time I use shutdown and I have to manually press the power button for 5 seconds to turn the machine off.

I've tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029068/ubuntu-18-04-stuck-at-shutdown?newreg=4f5908f34c2f4917902e976e50a35490) solution. it does not work for me. please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: have you solved this?
I'm kinda have a similar issue

Comment: @msmaromi maybe this answer would help you: https://askubuntu.com/a/1488548/781821

Answer (score 9):

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04.3 and, both the machines that I upgraded, faced this issue.

For me the issue was fixed on both the machines by installing the Nvidia driver version applicable for the Nvidia graphics card on the machines. This is the same solution that is linked in the question, and mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1049971/997759).

The graphics cards on my machines were GeForce RTX 3050 and GeForce RTX 3050 Ti, so I picked the correct driver version from [this site](https://www.nvidia.in/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-in). In essence, the search on the site is just used to identify the correct driver version.

[image]

Replacing the Nouveau driver by the Nvidia driver was done by simply installing the Nvidia driver (version 535 in my case). Specifically, I didn't have to explicitly remove the nouveau driver. Just running the command below worked for me.

**Note**: It's worth mentioning that don't just copy paste and run the command from below, but replace the *535* in the driver version with the driver version applicable for your hardware, the one identified from the search mentioned earlier.

```
$ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-535
```

Following a reboot, the machines were restored to their normal shutdown behaviour.

**Update**

Another point mentioned by Capitoneo in [his answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1484513/997759) is also relevant. The Additional Drivers section was blank after the upgrade to 22.04. After following the above steps even the additional drivers list got restored.

Comment: My error message was "ACPI BIOS Error, AE_NOT_FOUND". I upgraded the Nouveau drivers to Nvidia-drivers using your method above. This really worked!

Comment: when clicking accept and download on nvidia website nothing happens. Did you download the driver from the website or from the command line ? Did you uninstall old drivers first ?

Comment: @Ced - The website is used only to search for the correct driver version that is applicable for our specific hardware. I will clarify it in the answer. The driver itself is installed via the command line as mentioned in the answer. The nouveau driver is still installed on my setup but just not selected as the active one.

Comment: Just came across this from Facebook. This is the craziest thing! Does anyone have any idea how the graphics driver fixed this issue?

Comment: @Richard - I haven't looked into the root cause of this myself yet. I just looked for solutions and reported the steps that worked for me. From the limited understanding that I have, though crazy as it seems, this is still very much plausible. Drivers work closely with the kernel and a glitch somewhere can have seemingly unrelated side effects. Even if proprietary drivers don't go well with the spirit of open source, they still to me seem like the best bet for being most up to date, both bug fix wise and  functionally.

Answer (score 1):

just say my experience (on ubuntu22 today)
//not applicable in all situations

### check last poweroff log

after boot, check previous power off syslog.

```bash
journalctl -b -1 -r
```

- -b -1 //previous boot
- -r  //show log in reverse order

```
Nov 11 20:10:45 u22 systemd[1]: et.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
...
Nov 11 20:10:45 u22 systemd[1]: cups-browsed.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
...
Nov 11 20:09:16 u22 systemd[1731]: Reached target Shutdown.
```

It really wait 90 sec timeout..

### disable stuck service

mine was 2 service stop timeout,
// 90 seconds force stop as default.

- et.service
- cups-browsed

I don't use them, stop & disable it.

```bash
sudo systemctl stop et.service
sudo systemctl disable et.service

sudo systemctl stop cups-browsed
sudo systemctl disable cups-browsed
```

then poweroff succeed in 5 seconds.

ref:
https://www.cnblogs.com/apirobot/p/14528996.html

Answer (score 0):

I just did `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` and it fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was resolved by installing the GPU driver , NVIDIA in mycase GEFORCE RTX 3050, which I downloaded from the website https://www.nvidia.in/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-in

1. Ensure `cc` is already installed in your system in order to compile the driver  `sudo apt install build-essential`
2. Before Installing the driver, be ensure that service of `xserver` must be stopped, use following command

`sudo service lightdm stop`

2. goto tty terminal `sudo init 3`
3. Enter login and password and then go to folder where the driver is downloaded and execute the following command `sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-535.104.05.run`