# Can't reboot ubuntu after remove media installation because NetworkManager

Tags: boot, dual-boot

Tried to install Ubuntu 22.04.2 / Ubuntu 22.10 with dual boot via USB, on a erased hdd, after removing the media installation this show on screen:

```
[[ 1474.196531] shutdown[1]: Waiting for process: 1481 (NetworkManager), 1485 (wpa_supplicant)]
[ 1564.203778] shutdown[1]: Waiting for process: 1481 (NetworkManager), 1485 (wpa_supplicant)
[ 1644.272667] sd-umoun[77213]: Failed to unmount /oldroot: Device or resource busy
[ 1644.274888] sd-umoun[77214]: Failed to unmount /oldroot/run: Device or resource busy
[ 1644.277143] sd-umoun[77214]: Failed to unmount /oldroot/run: Device or resource busy
[ 1644.281419] shutdown[1]: Could not detach loopback /dev/loop0: Device or resource busy
[ 1644.283894] shutdown[1]: Failed to finalize file systems, loop devices, ignoring.
```

I tried changed in BIOS safe boot = disabled, put on boot Legacy and the same screen appers everytime I try to reinstall. The OS was once installed on de hdd and worked but was formated with DiskPart

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my Ubuntu `22.04.3 LTS` as in it got frozen in shutdown and restart. I manege with this solution to fix my problem:

First, remove all nvidia and cuda from your machine:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge '^libnvidia-.*'
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge '^cuda-.*'
```

Then

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

[*OPTIOAL*] Just check which drivers are available for your machine:

```
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers list
```

And you could install new default NVIDIA driver using:

```
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers install
```

To ensure you have successfully installed NVIDIA driver, simply run:

```
$ nvidia-smi
```

you should see you nvidia and cuda driver version.

And you reboot to ensure all have been successfully installed:

```
$ sudo reboot
```

It should work fine from now on, both for restarting and shutting down your machine.