# Ubuntu does not completely power off

Tags: shutdown

When i try to power off, the computer cannot be powered of completely.  The screen is still on. The screen looks like this: When i press ESC nothing happens. I tried to shutdown by terminal but the problem is still same.

[image: The screen looks like this]

Ubuntu Version : 22.04.3
Laptop : Asus Rog Zephyrus G14

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and tell us i) your Ubuntu version, ii) some details about your hardware (is that a laptop? What laptop? a desktop?), iii) whether you have any network devices mounted, iv) exactly how you shutdown, v) what happens if you open a terminal and shutdown with `sudo shutdown -h now`, vi) what happens if you press Esc when that screen is shown? Does that show any errors?

Comment: check the bios settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because something is still running.
You can try to use `dmesg` after the reboot to see if you have some information on that.

But your question is certainly a duplicate. You should check for "Ubuntu 22.04 won't stop" on this forum or google for example, there will be a lot of answer. E.g. : [Ubuntu 22.04 stuck at shutdown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1426205/ubuntu-22-04-stuck-at-shutdown)