Ubuntu 24.04 on Thinkpad-E560 doesn't shutdown properly
I recently bought an SSD, Installed ubuntu 24.04 from a bootable pendrive. Following the standard partition schema offered by the installer wizard. Then I noticed that my computer didn't shutdown properly as it keeps a little led blinking. I have to push the power button to really shutdown which I don't want to keep doing 'cause it can lead to errors. Right now I just have ubuntu on the entire SSD which I think can simplyfy things.
NOTE: I previusly had a dual boot for Windows and Ubuntu on a different SSD which passed away. But I think some BIOS configuration remain somewhere and it can be causing this unexpected behavior.
I've tried to look for some guidance on grub or editing it. But I'm pretty lost on how can I approach this.

It might be a service, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1426205/ubuntu-22-04-stuck-at-shutdown read the answer from community wiki  and if you use the service edit your question with what you find out.
