# Start up error text

Tags: boot

Starting with 23.04, whenever I start up my laptop, there's some text with a back screen that, in part, says "ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND." It didn't do this when I installed 22.04 and I was hoping 23.10 would fix it.

Does anyone have a solution so that it does a clean boot?

Also, it turns off normally, but, I would say, 1 out of 5 times, it shows a black screen with some text which in part says "PC is shutting down," but it doesn't shut down and stays stuck on the splash screen. This started in 23.10 and is definitely a bigger problem than the start up one because I have to press the power button for 5 seconds to do a force shut down when it happens.

Update: The start up error is too quick to get a picture of, but I did manage to get a pic of the shut down error.

[image]

Comment: I have to add that I just updated the 23.10 and now it keeps showing a notification saying "Important update installed" EVERY SINGLE TIME I turn on my laptop.

And the annoying "Pending update for Firefox Snap" notification is back. Ugh.

Comment: Maybe this threads helps, as it deals with a similar question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414169/acpi-error-ae-not-found-when-booting-after-upgrading-from-20-04-to-22-04

Comment: Thank you. I'll try modifying the BIOS.

Any ideas for why it's not shutting down properly sometimes?

Comment: Shutdown problems can occur when one ore more process can't be stopped correctly or hang when being stopped. It's a bit hard to track down, but you may want to check if the problem only occurs when you ran program X or Y or if it is really random.

Comment: That was my first thought. That maybe a process wasn't stopping correctly, but I can't seem to find a pattern.

Comment: I updated my BIOS by reinstalling the original Windows 11 SSD that had Lenovo's Vantage app to update the BIOS to GCCN33WW and putting back my Ubuntu SSD, but the A_E error still remains. It was worth a try.