# Ubuntu gives warning and I cannot change brightness of display

Tags: boot, drivers, brightness

When I turn on my laptop(Hp Victus 15) ubuntu gives warning before entering to system like this

```
0.2872551 ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolue symbol E_SB.PCI0.28.ECO
1, AE _NOT_FOUND (20221020/dsw load2-162)
0.2872751 ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During nane lookup/catalog (20221020/ps ob.ject-220)
0.7801461 and _gpio AMDI0030:00: Invalid config paran 0014
0.780174] and gpio AMD10030:00: Invalid config paran 0014
0.780195] and_gpio AMD10030:00: Invalid config param 0014
0.7802161 and _gpio AND10030:00: Invalid config paran 0014
0.7802361 and _gpio AMDI0030:00: Invalid config paran 0014
0.7802571 and _gpio AMD10030:00: Invalid config paran 0014
0.780277] and gpio AMDI0030:00: Invalid config paran 0014
0.7803021 and gpio AMDI0030:00: Invalid config paran 0014
0.7803221 and _gpio AMDI0030:00: Invalid config param 0014
1.4819881 and gpio AMD10030:00: Invalid config param 0014
1.4820221 and gpio AMDI0030:00: Invalid config paran 0001
```

And I cannot change brightness of display, i have two video adapters(video chip of processor and gtx 1650) and i have to monitors but i cannot change in my laptop's display
I use NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidea driver 535 (proprietary, tested) in additional drivers

Answer (score 0):

The messages you're seeing during start-up are really more FYIs than anything going critically wrong:

- [The amd_gpio errors are really internal debug messages that ended up getting shown unintentionally](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/2723), and will be switched back in a later Linux kernel edition
- [The ACPI errors are things that the computer's built-in BIOS essentially doesn't do that the Linux kernel expects](https://askubuntu.com/a/1414182/1639121), so some power management functions might not work exactly as intended

As far as brightness goes, given you have an HP laptop with dual AMD+Nvidia graphics as I do, the same instructions for directing the brightness control using a kernel parameter should work here as well - make sure when doing so that there are not other backlight-related kernel parameters, like `acpi_backlight`, in place at the same time:

- Follow the instructions on this page: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters to add the following kernel parameter: `amdgpu.backlight=0`
- For reference, after completing that process (the Permanent version at the bottom of the page), there is a line in my /etc/default/grub file that reads:
- `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash amdgpu.backlight=0"`

Hope this helps.